# update database with jsp

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

I try to update table in mysql database  from jsp using this method:

```
<form >
<input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" name="bt2">
<input type="submit" value="Skicka Tips" onclick="a()">
</form>

<script> function a(){
try
{
  // create a java mysql database connection
  String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentEnrollment";
  Class.forName(myDriver);
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "12");

  // create the java mysql update preparedstatement
  String query = "update etudiants set dv_o_math = ? where first_name = ?";
  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  preparedStmt.setInt(1, 15);
  preparedStmt.setString(2,request.getParameter("bt2"));

  // execute the java preparedstatement
  preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

  conn.close();
}catch (Exception )
{ }

}
```

but still not working .how can I fix the code to get result.

Rq: I did import  java.sql.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code written inside a  tag is executed by the browser on the client machine Eg: JavaScript code to perform client side validations. To connect to the database , the code must be executed on the server and not on the client machine for which you are using JSP which is a server side scripting language.

Use scriptlets tags <%%> to write the code that has to be executed on the server before the webpage is sent to the client machine/browser.

Seems like you are a beginner in JSP. Would recommend you to go through some of the online JSP and Servlet Tutorials.

For now , try using the below code :
**a.html**

```
<form action="FetchData.jsp">
<input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" name="bt2" >
<input type="submit" value="Skicka Tips">
</form>
```

**FetchData.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
try
{
  // create a java mysql database connection
  String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentEnrollment";
  Class.forName(myDriver);
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "12");

  // create the java mysql update preparedstatement
  String query = "update etudiants set dv_o_math = ? where first_name = ?";
  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  preparedStmt.setInt(1, 15);
  preparedStmt.setString(2,request.getParameter("bt2"));

  // execute the java preparedstatement
  preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

  conn.close();
}catch (Exception e){ }

%>
<h3> The data is successfully updated</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

the fact of setting `onclick="a()"` is waiting from you to execute a Javascript function whcih will be executed in the client side and not the server side so in your case this code will never work as you are expecting 
try to work on this , so instead of putting that java code between a  tag try to put it on a scriplet `<% "your java code here" %>` here is a start try to work on it

```
<form >
<input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" name="bt2">
<input type="submit" value="Skicka Tips" name="a">
</form>
```

and in the same file you put your java code between a scriplet like this

```
    <%
    if(request.getParameter("a")!=null){ // this is to avoid null pointer exception
      try{
      // create a java mysql database connection
      String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentEnrollment";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "12");

      // create the java mysql update preparedstatement
      String query = "update etudiants set dv_o_math = ? where first_name = ?";
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setInt(1, 15);
      preparedStmt.setString(2,request.getParameter("bt2"));

      // execute the java preparedstatement
      preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

      conn.close();
    } 
}catch(Exception e ){
e.getMessage();
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to perform database operations from a JSP (as Shubhi224 has demonstrated), *this isn't something that you actually want to be doing*. This approach is termed "Model 1" architecture, and results in undesirable tight coupling between your display logic (the "view"), your business logic (the "model"), and your database access code (the "repository").

Just as your Java classes should adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle (classes should have only one reason to change), your JSPs should have just one responsibility too: to render the view.

"Model 2" architecture was developed as a response to the limitations of having JSPs performing too many responsibilities. Model 2 is also known as MVC (it's actually MVC adapted for the http/browser-based Web architecture).

I would strongly recommend researching MVC, in order to learn how to properly separate out the responsibilities within your application. MVC is also frequently used with the Controller-Service-Repository pattern, whereby your database access code is performed in your Repository classes. I would recommend researching this design pattern also.